# Meteor on Github, how can I work on same project with a friend

Tags: javascript, git, github, meteor

I am a total programming newbie.
If I upload my Meteor project to Github and after clone it, I cant run it in Meteor anymore, it will crash. 
When I delete the local entry in .gitignore then it works. 
But then with every lil change many local files change and the github commits look messy.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to run `meteor create app-name` for meteor to create the local folder and the various things it needs in there such as mongodb etc and then clone your repo into that folder. You don't want this content in the repo so keep your `.gitignore` file but you both need your own local copies of local folder for the app to run.

Or link to the repo if it's public and I'll see if I can run it/what errors pop up.